# Google Sheet PHP API v.4: how can I add a "stop" row in a Sheet?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm not sure of the correct terminology to use, but what I need to do is add a row in a Google Sheet that "stops" the PHP API v.4 from getting any more data from the sheet.

I have a Sheet with hundreds of rows of data that I am getting via the API, and below the rows I want are some formula fields that I don't want (and I can't change their location in the Sheet or delete them.)

How can I add something like "99999" to the A cell in a row that tells the API to stop at the row before it?

Or is there a better way to tell the API to stop?

This is what I'm using in the Sheets v.4 PHP API to get rows from the sheet. The data is delimited by `\n` newlines.

```
// authentication not shown
$range = 'Sheet3!AD2:Z';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

// This explode strings into array
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));

// This assigns variables that are used to echo the data
$firstname = $valuearray[0];
$lastname = $valuearray[1];
$address = $valuearray[2];
$city = $valuearray[3];
$state = $valuearray[4];
$zip = $valuearray[5];
```

That gives me an output like this:

> Joe\nSmith\n123 Dogpatch Lane\nDog  Town\nAlabama\n34567
>
> John\nJones\n456 Cat Hollow\nCat Town\nArkansas\n12345

and on and on...

What I need to do is add a row with something - like 999999 - in an A cell that stops the API on the previous row.

[image]

**Update 12/15/21 --------------------**

I must have been overthinking it; this works and is as simple as possible:

```
// This explode strings into array
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));

// This assigns variables that are used to echo the data
$firstname = $valuearray[0];
$lastname = $valuearray[1];
$address = $valuearray[2];
$city = $valuearray[3];
$state = $valuearray[4];
$zip = $valuearray[5];

if($firstname==='999999') { break; } // Break on 999999 in the firstname field

echo '<h1 class="firstname">' . $firstname . '</h1>';
......
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `I still get those errors`. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. And from `This all may have to do with possibly a not good way that I explode/implode the arrays and assign variables.`, I deeply apologize that my proposed answer was not useful. From this, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill. I think that I have to study more and more.

Comment: Are you looking for `if($firstname==='999999') { break; }`?

Comment: @Tanaike You're obviously very skilled, with am 118K rep! :) I'm trying to do something very out of the ordinary and it may not be possible in a clean way. I appreciate your help! I PayPal'd you for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to confirm your current issue, can I ask you about my proposed script again? Where line in my proposed script does the error of `I get Warning: Undefined array key 0 and Undefined array key 2041 on the line if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") and also Undefined array key 1, etc. right after the 99999 from the sheet.` occur?

Comment: I check the [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342165/14271633) answer an is working for me with the spreadsheets that you share. Can you confirm that is also working for you?

Comment: @idfurw Thanks, that works; and it's the simplest. I must have been overthinking the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values by checking whether the value of column "A" is `99999`. When the value of column "A" is `99999`, you don't want to retrieve the values after this line.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for php.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be directly achieved using Sheets API. So, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```php
$range = 'Sheet3!AD2:Z';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);

// --- I added below script.
$v = $response['values'];
$values = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= count($v); $i++){
    if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") {
        break;
    }
    array_push($values, $v[$i]);
}
// ---

// This explode strings into array
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray =explode("\n", implode($val));
```

- By this, the values can be retrieved by checking the value of column "A".

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

### Added:

About your following updated script,

```
// authentication not shown
$range = 'Sheet3!AD2:Z';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

// This explode strings into array
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));

// This assigns variables that are used to echo the data
$firstname = $valuearray[0];
$lastname = $valuearray[1];
$address = $valuearray[2];
$city = $valuearray[3];
$state = $valuearray[4];
$zip = $valuearray[5];
```

In your script, `$values` is 2 dimensional array. And when your sample Spreadsheet of the image is used, it's like `[["Joe","Null","blah blah","Smith","123 Dogpatch Lane","Dog Town","Alabama",34567],,,]`. So when `$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));` is run, `["Joe","Null","blah blah","Smith","123 Dogpatch Lane","Dog Town","Alabama",34567]` is converted to `["JoeNullblah blahSmith123 Dogpatch LaneDog TownAlabama34567"]`. By this, `$firstname = $valuearray[0]` occurs no error. But `$lastname` to `$zip` occurs an error. Because the array length is `1`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. If you want to put each value to `$firstname` to `$zip`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));

// This assigns variables that are used to echo the data
$firstname = $valuearray[0];
$lastname = $valuearray[1];
$address = $valuearray[2];
$city = $valuearray[3];
$state = $valuearray[4];
$zip = $valuearray[5];
```

#### To:

```
foreach($values as $val) {
    if (count($val) > 0 && $val[0] == 99999) {
        break;
    }
    list($firstname, $lastname, $address, $city, $state, $zip) = $val;
}
```

or

```
$v = $values;
$values = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= count($v); $i++){
    if (count($v[$i]) > 0 && $v[$i][0] == 99999) {
            break;
    }
    array_push($values, $v[$i]);
}
foreach($values as $val) {
    list($firstname, $lastname, $address, $city, $state, $zip) = $val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it in the API. But I get Warning: Undefined array key 0 and Undefined array key 2041  on the line `if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999")` and also Undefined array key 1, etc. right after the 99999 from the sheet.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'll set up a public Sheet with sample data and link it here. The Sheet I'm working with is private and requites authorization, but there shouldn't be too much difference to test with the public sheet.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying. When I could replicate your current issue using the sample Spreadsheet, it will help to think of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's a sample csv file; of course you'll need to change the \n to , in the $valuearray. https://shorturl.at/vDRU1

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying and providing your CSV sample. When I tested my proposed script using your sample CSV data, no error occurs. And the values from 1 to 4 rows can be retrieved. So I cannot replicate your situation of `Warning: Undefined array key 0 and Undefined array key 2041 on the line if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") and also Undefined array key 1, etc. right after the 99999 from the sheet.`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch In your situation, when you use your sample CSV data, the same issue can be replicated? I'm worried about this. I apologize for this.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch For example, when you modified my proposed script from `if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") {` to `if (count($v[$i]) > 0 && strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") {` or `if (count($v[$i]) > 0 && $v[$i][0] == 99999) {`, your issue can be removed?

Comment: I appreciate your help, I still get those errors. This all may have to do with possibly a not good way that I explode/implode the arrays and assign variables. Also, I edited my question; I forgot to add some code that I use.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch From your updated script, I thought that your current issue might be other part except for my proposed script. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch For example, if you want to output each row value like `Joe\nSmith\n123 Dogpatch Lane\nDog Town\nAlabama\n34567` in your question, please replace `list($firstname, $lastname, $address, $city, $state, $zip) = $val;` to `$res = join("\n", $val);`. By this, `$res` is the value like that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm still getting errors; this is a real mystery. I will do some more tests later today. Do you think that method I'm using - explode/implode and the array to assign variables - is not the best method to extract the data? Would php map be better? Would that be an easier method to allow the detection of the stop data 99999?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying. About `I'm still getting errors; this is a real mystery.`, when you tested my additional script, the same error of `I get Warning: Undefined array key 0 and Undefined array key 2041 on the line if (strval($v[$i][0]) == "99999") and also Undefined array key 1, etc.`. Is my understanding correct? In my additional modification, I don't use `explode` and `implode`. So at first, I thought that it is required to correctly understand your current situation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still testing things here tonight; will let you know.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying. I will wait for it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks again. I must have been overthinking things; I used `if($firstname==='999999') { break; }` and that works. I still got errors using `list($firstname, $lastname, $address,...` for some reason rather than implode and explode, and that's a puzzle. It appears that using implode and explode is not the best thing to do, but it works for now.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I deeply apologize my answer was not useful. But I think that this answer might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave this.

Comment: I was a little confused with what I was trying to do, as I'm still learning php, but your answer was helpful and I appreciate your time, so yes, leave it here. I've been looking at your Github, and it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I appreciate your reply.